# Regex to accept 6 or 8 digits followed by 0, 1 or 2 letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regular expression to accept first 6 or 8 digit then d, m, md, DM or no letter at all
e.g.

1. 121212 - valid
2. 12121212 - valid
3. 121212d - valid
4. 121212md - valid

I have written

```
/(^(\d{6}|\d{8}))(d|m|dm|md|)$/gi
```

is it correct or wrong?

Comment: You can check it on https://regex101.com/

Comment: You could probably do the suffix as (dm?|md?). Apart from that, looks a-ok. You just need to test it.

Comment: How about `^(\d{6}|\d{8})(dm?|md?| )$`

Comment: May I know why this question is downvoted while OP has shown his efforts?

Comment: The *is it correct or wrong?* question is the same as "what does my pattern mean/what can my pattern match", and is thus a dupe. If you find any issues with the pattern, specify what is wrong, update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with:

```
^\d{6}(?:\d{2})?(?:md?|dm?)?$
```

`(?:\d{2})?` stands for 2 optional more digits.
`(?:md?|dm?)?` stands for optional `m` or `d`, followed or not by its mate.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uUQUTR/2)

Comment: Won't this make  `121212mm` and `121212dd` valid ?

Comment: Absolutely right. I edited my answer to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

You should do something like `\d{6,8}[a-zA-Z]{2}`.
Or
`[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}`

Have a nice day

Comment: This will allow any letters at the end - not just d and m.

Comment: And it'll allow 7 digits.

Comment: Yes you right you can change the [a-zAZ] by (md?|dm?) tell me if its ok

Comment: You need `(md?|dm?| )/gi` to allow for no letters.

Comment: Sorry i miss understood ^^ in this case your’s ok